# WebView + фоновый audio сервис для уведомлений о событиях

Tags: android, webview

Здравствуйте!

Делаю приложение для своего мобильного сайта на основе `AdvancedWebView`, звуковые `html5` `audio` уведомления работают, запускаются из `js` скриптов при появления нового события, но если приложение свёрнуто, то уведомления перестают работать, погуглил и нашёл другое решение - создать фоновый аудио сервис, который крутился бы в фоне и проигрывал уведомления, если появились новые события, инфу об этой фиче нагуглил тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717293/making-webview-audio-play-in-background

Но так как только начинаю осваивать написание приложения под `Android` и практически не знаю нюансов Java, многое пока не понятно, знаю только `PHP` + `JS`, а в примере из ссылки сервис пишется видимо для полностью нативного способа, без `WebView`, в связи с этим вопрос, возможно ли в этом аудио сервисе посылать запросы к веб серверу, чтобы узнать о появлении новых событий? 
И как быть с `cookies`, как их вытащить из `WebView` для моего домена, чтобы из аудио сервиса на сервер отправлялся запрос авторизованного пользователя, после того как он авторизовался в основном приложении? Или это делается как-то иначе?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, любые варианты, в какую сторону нужно копать.

Было бы идеальным в этом же сервисе включить уведомление вибрацией, в самом приложении этого добился, но тоже работает только в случае, если приложение активно и не свёрнуто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снимается, всё решил, оставлю ответ на случай, если кому-то пригодится.

1. создать MainActivity, например, с `WebView`.
2. создать сервис стандартными средствами Android Studio кликнув на MainActivity правой кнопкой, new -> service -> service
3. Называем сервис, например, PlayService и вставляем в него примерно такой код:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;`

public class PlayService extends Service {

    private MediaPlayer NewMessage;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        NewMessage = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.new_message);
        NewMessage.setLooping(false);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        AutoPlay();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        NewMessage.release();
    }
    
    void AutoPlay(){

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                while (true) 
                {
                    if(MainActivity.breakservice == 1) {break;} /* в MainActivity в событии onResume устанавливаем переменной breakservice значение 1, чтобы остановить цикл, когда приложение активно, в событии onPause значение 0, чтобы активировать цикл */

                    startDataRequest(); //получение json строки с веб сервера

                    try {
                        
                        Thread.sleep(5000); //выполнять действия в сервисе каждые 5 сек. 

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void startDataRequest() {
        new GetDataTask().execute();
    }

    private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response> {
        
        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(Void... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Cookie", MainActivity.WebViewCookies)
                    .url("http://m.site.ru").build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    String responseData = response.body().string();
                    
                    StringToJson(responseData);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            } else {

            }
        }

        protected String StringToJson(String jsonString) {

            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                //jsonString - json строка полученная в ответ веб сервера каждые n сек., в ней определяется, что делать в этом блоке

                if(obj.getString("action") == "play_new_message") {
                    NewMessage.start();
                }

                //... что-то ещё

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("action"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (Throwable tx) {

            }

            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

4. в MainActivity после объявления класса создаём переменные

```
public static String WebViewCookies;
```

5. в MainActivity в событии onPause добавляем

```
final String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("m.site.ru");
WebViewCookies = cookie;
breakservice = 0;`
if(isMyServiceRunning(PlayService.class) == false) {
   startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class));
}
```

6. в MainActivity в событии onResume добавляем

```
breakservice = 1;
```

7. в класс MainActivity добавляем метод

   ```
   private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
       ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
       for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
           if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

В манифесте в моём случае следующие разрешения:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Все они необходимы именно в моём случае, в вашем может быть не все они нужны, или наоборот их может быть больше, в зависимости от того, что делает ваше приложение.

Хочу отметить, что это моё первое приложение на Android, поэтому наверняка многое сделано неправильно.

Вот и всё.

Логика работы в моём случае такая: Пока приложение активно, звуковые и вибро уведомления о событиях выполняются средствами js сайта + html5, когда приложение сворачивается или закрывается в работу вступает фоновый сервис, если приложение вновь запускается, то сервис свою работу останавливает и ждёт, когда приложение опять перестанет быть активным.

Буду рад если кому-нибудь это пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Если надо в фоне - только через нативные средства, имхо.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но на данном этапе вряд ли смогу переписать всю логику нативно. К тому же видел уже одно приложение, которое попутно с собой запускает фоновый сервис, и в этом сервисе крутится геолокация, и по идее как-то отправляет геоданные по конкретному пользователю, как-то его идентифицирует.  Думаете стартовать сервис с `cookies` из `WebView` не получится, например, при сворачивании приложения?

Comment: Получилось сделать фоновый сервис, проигрывает файлы, думаю сделать теперь бесконечный цикл и в нём слать каждые n сек. запрос, чтобы получить события, проблема теперь осталась только в том, чтобы отправлять авторизованный запрос вместе с `coockie`, получить `coockie` из `WebView` оказалось вполне реальным, но теперь не понятно при каком событии стартовать сервис из приложения, ведь нужно его стартануть когда пользователь успешно авторизовался, а авторизация происходит на стороне веб сервера, поэтому события `onPageStarted` или `onPageFinished` не подходят...

Comment: При сворачивании webview к сожалению отключается. Сам хотел сделать будильник - получилось только через натив

Comment: Так надо на событие `onPause` повесить старт сервиса, с предварительной проверкой запущен ли сервис, если нет, то запускать, я эту проблему решил, уже решил и все остальные, кроме последней - выдёгивания `cookies` из `WebView` и передачу их в сервис, но принцип уже понял, времени не хватило сегодня доделать.

Comment: Я сделал так: объявил переменную - флаг в MainActivity, в onPause присваиваю ей значение 0, проверяю запущен ли сервис, если нет стартую, в onResume флагу присваиваю 1, а в сервисе в "вечном" цикле проверяю флаг на значение 1, если 1, то прерываю цикл. Получается, что когда приложение уходит спать - включается цикл в сервисе и выполняются нужные дела, а при восстановлении приложения цикл в сервисе прерывается. Получилось именно то, что и хотел.